# Replace periods with substitution in bash script using perl except questionmark or exclamation mark

Tags: bash, perl, substring, substitution

Originally I figured out how to remove the periods for all the files and then add them back:

```
 Remove periods at end of titles
 perl -pi -e 's/title = \{(.*)\.\},/title = \{$1\},/g' $1
 # Add periods back so all files are the same (comment out if no periods wanted)
 perl -pi -e 's/title = \{(.*)\},/title = \{$1\.\},/g' $1
```

Ideally what I want to do is check if every title has a period, exclamation mark, or question mark and if it doesn't then add a period. I assume there is a simple way to do this substitution but I don't know the syntax well.

So for example for input:

```
title = This has a period.
title = This has nothing
title = This has a exclamation!
title = This has a question?
```

The output will be:

```
title = This has a period.
title = This has nothing.
title = This has a exclamation!
title = This has a question?
```

So it only modifies lines to had a period if it ended without any markings.

Comment: Provide sample input (all possible cases - with/without periods at the end.) and their respective outputs...

Comment: @anishsane It's been added

Comment: Also, what to do, if there are multiple `.` at the end? `title = This has multiple periods...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KISS, Use negated character class.

```
perl -pi -e 's/title = \{(.*[^.?!])\},/title = \{$1\.\},/g' $1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tG6gS6/1)

or

Use negative lookbehind.

```
perl -pi -e 's/title = \{(.*)(?<![.?!])\},/title = \{$1\.\},/g' $1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tG6gS6/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/^title = .*[.!?]$/!s/$/./' file
```

(OR)

```
sed '/^title = .*[^.!?]$/s/$/./' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed '/^title = .*[.!?]$/!s/$/./' file
title = This has a period.
title = This has nothing.
title = This has a exclamation!
title = This has a question?
```